# Recursive function adds characters onto the end of char array

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function that, given a directory, will recurse through the directory and print out the contents (think the "tree" linux command).

Anyways, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIRECTORY 4

void recurseDirectory(const char* path, int level);
int isDirectory(const char *filename);
void printLevel(int level);

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    char *directory;
    DIR *pdir = NULL;
    struct dirent *pent = NULL;
    FILE curFile;

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Missing argument: directory. Exitting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
directory = argv[1];
recurseDirectory(directory, 0);
}


void recurseDirectory(const char *path, int level){
  struct dirent *pent = NULL;
  char *full_path;
  DIR *pdir = opendir(path);

  if (pdir){
    while (pent = readdir(pdir)){
      if(pent != NULL){
    if(pent->d_type == DIRECTORY){

      //add 1 for '/' character
      full_path = calloc(strlen(pent->d_name) + strlen(path) + 1, 0);
      if (full_path){

        strncpy(full_path, path, strlen(path));
        strcat(full_path, "/");
        strcat(full_path, pent->d_name);

        printLevel(level);

        printf("%s\n", path);

        printf("\nDEBUG: path: %s, new_dir: %s\n", path, pent->d_name);
        printf("DEBUG: full_path: %s\n\n", full_path);

        recurseDirectory(full_path, level + 1);
        free(full_path);
      }else{
        printf("Failed to recurse on %s\n", pent->d_name);
      } 
    }else{
      if(pent->d_type != 0){
        printLevel(level);
        printf("%s\n", pent->d_name);
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}

void printLevel(int level){
  while (level != 0){
    printf("%s", "    ");
    level--;
  }
}
```

Here is a sample run, notice between the debug print to the next call of the function, that the value of path is **not** the value that was passed in.

```
./a.out ..

..

DEBUG: path: .., new_dir: personal_proj
DEBUG: full_path: ../personal_proj

    a.out
    recurse_dir.c
..

DEBUG: path: .., new_dir: junk
DEBUG: full_path: ../junk

    ../junk

DEBUG: path: ../junk, new_dir: project
DEBUG: full_path: ../junk/project

        ../junk/projectA�  **right here **

DEBUG: path: ../junk/projectA�, new_dir: part1
DEBUG: full_path: ../junk/projectA�/part1

*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000252a560 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7cbac)[0x7f5205d40bac]
```

I've been banging my head against this one because it's making absolutely no sense to me. Especially because it's printing out two completely different values between calling and entering the function.

Thank you for any help anyone can offer me.

Comment: If you understood [tag:c-strings] you wouldn't be using `strcat()` like that. Please read what [tag:c-strings] are and try to think of a better solution.

Comment: `calloc(strlen(pent->d_name) + strlen(path) + 1, 0);` : `0` ???

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi That doesn't exactly help. Do you mean I should change strcpy(full_path, "/") to something null terminated? If so, I tried that and it has the same error. Please let me know.

Comment: No, read [tag:c-strings] and think. Why would I say something like that? There is a reason, if you understand what a [tag:c-strings] is you can think of how does `strcat()` work. And you would know how to manipulate your strings better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't notice this at first,

```
full_path = calloc(strlen(pent->d_name) + strlen(path) + 1, 0);
```

but this is wrong, because none of `calloc()` arguments makes sense to be `0`. Instead, attempt

```
name_length = strlen(pent->d_name);
path_length = strlen(path);
full_path = malloc(name_length + path_length + 1);
```

There is a caveat in using `strncpy()`. While it's safe in the sense that you will not write more than `n` characters, it's dangerous because it will skip the `'\0'` if it's not present within the first `n` characters, so

```
strcpy(full_path, path);
```

should fix your problem.

More,

1. Don't `calloc()` unless you do want to initialize all bytes to `0`. Mainly because, you could hide a bug in your logic because this way the string is `'\0'` terminated regardless of whether you perform the correct calculations or not.
2. Don't use `strcat()` like that, use `snprintf()` which is better suited for what you want.
3. Don't call `strlen()` more than once on the same unmodified string.

**Regarding my comment about not using** `strcat()`: `strcat()` is ok if you just use it once, because there is no better way to concatenate two strings, but using it multiple times is inefficient.

Since strings in c are `null` terminated arrays of `char`, you can concatenate strings directly by storing their lengths and using `memcpy()`, in this case you need to store the length anyway to compute the final size and allocate the appropriate amount of memory, going back to my example about how to allocate memory correctly we can do this

```
name_length = strlen(pent->d_name);
path_length = strlen(path);
full_path = malloc(name_length + path_length + 2);
if (full_path != NULL) {
    memcpy(full_path, path, path_length);
    full_path[path_length] = '/';
    memcpy(full_path + path_length + 1, pent->d_name, name_length);
    full_path[path_length + name_length + 1] = '\0';
}
```

This is not unsafe because you compute the length of the resulting string and allocate enough space for it, then use the information to populate it step by step.

While you can achieve this with `strcat()` and without storing the lengths, you should always remember that string lengths are not stored anywhere in a c program, and that everytime you use `strcpy()`, `strcat()` or `strlen()` the program will scan the string to find the terminating `'\0'`.